# Implementing threads/callable adds 50% to my execution time, why is this?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, multitasking

I'm currently learning multithreading, but I have some problems understanding what's going wrong in my code.

I'm trying to fill two lists with random data by calling my function `threadPopulateList()`. In my understanding, this should start two threads in parallel, as I call the method twice.

But, my execution time goes up by ~50% when using the `threadmethod`.

Code:

```
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    long start=System.currentTimeMillis();

    /**Populate lists after eachother gives --> 4211 ms */
    //        List<DATA>list1normal = populateNormal(9999999);
    //        List<DATA>list2normal = populateNormal(9999999);

    /**Populate list simoultaniously/parralel --> 6500ms???*/
    List<DATA>list1normal = threadPopulateList(9999999);
    List<DATA>list2normal = threadPopulateList(9999999);

    long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long executionTime = stop-start;
    System.out.println(executionTime+" ms");

}

/**Method to populate list*/
static List<DATA> populateNormal(int amount){
    List<DATA>data = new ArrayList<>();
    Random rn = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        data.add(new DATA(rn.nextInt(1000),rn.nextInt(1000), rn.nextInt(1000)));
    }
    return data;
}

/**Method to start a thread for each call so list will populate simoultiously*/
static List<DATA> threadPopulateList(int amount) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    List<DATA> data = new ArrayList<>();
    Random rn = new Random();
    Callable<List<DATA>> callable = () -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            data.add(new DATA(rn.nextInt(1000), rn.nextInt(1000), rn.nextInt(1000)));
        }
        return data;
    };
    Future<List<DATA>> result = executor.submit(callable);
    executor.shutdown();
    return result.get();
   }
}
```

Comment: You're creating **two** lists, both are filled by a **single** thread. What you probably wanted is to create a **single** list that is filled by **two** threads?

Comment: Unrelated: follow java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase, not SOLIDUPPERCASE. What you do there is extremely misleading, as one could easily assume DATA isnt a class name but a generic type parameter.

Comment: @Lino My intention was really to fill 2 seperate lists a the same time, so in parralel. And then to see how much faster it was.  2 tasks 2 threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually creating two serialized tasks with internal threading that doesn't really do anything. If you want to parallelize, you need to try something more like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        long start=System.nanoTime();
        int amount = 9999999;
        populateNormal(amount);
        populateNormal(amount);
        long stop = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Normal execution completed in " + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(stop - start)+"ms");
        
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        start = System.nanoTime();
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
        executor.submit(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                populateNormal(amount);
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
        
        executor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                populateNormal(amount);
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
        latch.await();
        stop = System.nanoTime();
        executor.shutdown();        
        System.out.println("Threaded execution completed in " + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(stop-start)+"ms");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code example! i wasnt able to get it working so this helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`Callable` is the task to be performed.  Your code has only one `Callable` so it can only be executed on one thread.

Even though you created a `ThreadPool` with two threads in it, since you have only one task, one of the threads is guaranteed to be idle.

In addition, you are filling out the list twice, so your one task is going to be twice as long as it was when you filled the list once.

I would try creating two `Callable`s each to process 1/2 the data in the list; and, then scheduling them both.  Once they are both done, combine the results into a final "output" list.

The reason your solution only adds 50% to the time, and not 100% to the time is because your benchmark probably includes the time to start the JVM and begin processing.  This means that your overall breakdown of the original program was probably "execution time = startup time + processing time" where startup time was about 1/2 of the execution time.

Comment: Thank you for replying, i will give it a try!